# New tableview cell selection controls previous tableview cell selection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview with custom tableview cells that are each associated with a specific audio file.  Each cell also has a progress bar inside.  When selecting a row, I can play the audio file associated with the cell.  However, if a cell is already playing and I tap another cell, the audio player will play the new audio file, but the progress bar of the previously selected cell will move along with the progress bar of my newly selected cell.  I tried using `deselectRowAtIndexPath` but no luck.

```
//Selecting row in table view 
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSDictionary * packageInArray = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [((OSAudioTableCell*)[self.audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) rowSelected:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"audioData"]];
}

//Method in custom tableview cell 
-(void) rowSelected: (NSData*) data
{
    if(self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying == YES)
    {
        [self.audioPlayer.player stop];
        [self.waveView setProgress:0];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = NO;
    }

    self.audioPlayer = [OSTablePlayerController getInstance];
    [self.audioPlayer playAudio:data];
    self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = YES;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.0001 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: We're not mind readers. Show your code.

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry.  I figured it would be better to get a general answer on how to stop all activity within a cell whenever a new cell is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an indexPath reference of the previously playing cell. Then, implement a new method on your custom cell to stop playing the audio.

Here's some sample code:

```
        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        { 
            NSDictionary * packageInArray = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [((OSAudioTableCell*)[self.audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) rowSelected:[packageInArray objectForKey:@"audioData"]];

            if(previousCellIndexPath != nil) {

                 [((OSAudioTableCell*)[self.audioTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousCellIndexPath]) rowDeselected];
            }

            previousCellIndexPath = indexPath;
           // this index path will become 'previous' on the next didSelectRow for future use
        }
```

Change the rowSelected method to only play music for the newly selected cell:

```
//Method in custom tableview cell 
    -(void) rowSelected: (NSData*) data
    {
        self.audioPlayer = [OSTablePlayerController getInstance];
        [self.audioPlayer playAudio:data];
        self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = YES;
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.0001 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
```

Finally, implement a new method to stop music for the previously selected cell:

```
-(void)rowDeselected
{
            [self.audioPlayer.player stop];
            [self.waveView setProgress:0];
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = NO;
}
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Well the audio of the previous cell does stop playing with my current code.  Its just the progress bar of the previous cell pretty much mirrors the progress bar of the newly selected cell.

Comment: The audio stops because it can play only one audio at a time. The implementation I have provided also clears the cell content based on the code in your question.

Comment: Wow worked like a charm.  In the first block of code you provided, the  rowDeselcted method should be called before the rowSelected method. Other than that, your code is spot on!